# In how many $3$ letters word can be arranged from the word 'MOVIES'?

Tags: permutations

In how many $3$ letters word can be arranged from the word 'MOVIES'?

my answer is $^6P_3=120$

is the answer correct?

Comment: yes this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes . Since there are no repeating letters hence there will by only one case of $3$ lettered word that is all letters being different . Hence answer will be $^6P_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's correct since none of the letters are repeating.